# Testing using fake object PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a Router class which have 3 params: the pattern, the callback, and the http method.
If the callback is ControllerDispatch object, it will call the controller and execute the action.

I don't know how to test the controller dispatch.
This is my piece of code of DispatcherTest.php

```
public function testControllerDispatch()
{
    $controller = new Routeria\Tests\FakeController;
    $this->collection->addRoute(new Route('/testController/{id:int}', new ControllerDispatch($controller, 'fakeMethod')));
    $request = $this->getMockBuilder('\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request')
                        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                        ->getMock();
    $request->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getPathInfo')
            ->will($this->returnValue('/testController/55'));
    $request->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getMethod')
            ->will($this->returnValue('GET'));
    $this->router->route($request);
    $this->expectOutputString('Hello user id: 55');
    $this->dispatcher->dispatch();
}
```

All the test is in the test directory as shown as the picture below.. The FakeController is also included

[image: Test Directory]

And, this is the bootstrap file

```
<?php
 $loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
 $loader->add('Routeria\Tests', __DIR__);
```

This is my fake controller

```
<?php
namespace Routeria\Tests;

    class FakeController
    {
        public function fakeMethod($fakeID)
        {
            echo 'Hello user id: '.$fakeID;
        }
    }
```

And, This is my phpunit.xml.dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
     bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    >
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Routeria Testing">
        <directory>./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>./src/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Why don't it works ?
It says "Fatal Error Class 'Routeria\Tests\FakeController' not found"
Please help..
If you want to see the code, I've uploaded it to my git : https://github.com/terryds/routeria

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Finally I've got the solution!
I namespaced the tests with Routeria\Tests, and the helper class/ fake object with Routeria\TestHelper
I modified this bootstrap.php into:

```
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->setPsr4('Routeria\\Tests\\', __DIR__);
$loader->setPsr4('Routeria\\TestHelper\\', __DIR__ . '/src');
```

Then, it works !